# Contrasts with 2 or more degrees of freedom in R

Tags: r

In SAS, it is possible to specify directly  contrasts with two or more degrees of freedom (df); by example with the following code:

```
CONTRAST “CONT2DF”  TREAT -1 -1 2,
TREAT 1 -1 0;
```

In R, it is possible to utilize `emmeans::test(contrast, joint=T)`  to obtain contrast with two or more df.
Also with `rms::contrast(f, type='joint')`, the same result.
But, without depending of any other library that stats, how to obtain the following?;

---

```
library(tidyr)

set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(a=rnorm(20, 8,1), b=rnorm(20, 14,2), c=rnorm(20, 4,0.5),d=rnorm(20, 19,2))
data <- gather(data, key=Treat, value=y)
data$Treat<-as.factor(data$Treat)
c1<-c(1,-1,-1,-1)/3
c2<-c(0, 1,1,-2)/2
c3<-c(0,0,1,-1)

contrast2df<-??? (c1,c2)  # Here the doubt 

finalcontrasts <- cbind(contrast2df, c3)
contrasts(data$Treat) <- finalcontrasts

CList = list("contrast2df" = 1,
             "c3" = 2)


model <- aov(y~Treat, data=data)
summary(model, split=list(Trat=CList))

# Equivalent to :

library(emmeans)
model1 <- lm(y~Treat, data=data)
finalcontrastsem <- list(c1, c2, c3)
medias <- emmeans(model, ~Treat)

step1 <- contrast(medias, finalcontrastsem[1:2])
test(step1, joint=T)

step2 <- contrast(medias, finalcontrastsem[3])
test(step2, joint=T)
```

Comment: Why do you not want to depend on any library except stats?

Comment: To use the contrasts with two or more df in bayesian models (brms ans rstanarm) for posterior prediction.

Comment: For example;     tidybayes::gather_emmeans_draws(step1) , with step1 containing one or more contrasts with 2 or more df, and single df contrasts too.

Comment: If you get the contrasts you want, e.g. `con <- contrast(...)`, then `con@linfct` contains the associated linear functions of the fixed effects. Does that help?

Comment: Also `coda::as.mcmc(con)` has the posterior samples of those contrasts (provided you fitted a Baesian model).

Comment: Russ, thank you very much for your help,  and by the wonderful package emmeans.